# LAMP на Ubuntu 16.04 не работает. что не так?

Tags: php, ubuntu, настройка, lamp

Приветствую всех!
Только знакомлюсь с PHP. С самого начала возникло множество проблем.
В PHP отсутствует предустановленный локальный сервер. В связи с этим возникло много проблем.

Не получилось установить LAMP. по мануалам:
[http://help.ubuntu.ru/fullcircle/22/веб-разработка_ч3](http://help.ubuntu.ru/fullcircle/22/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%873)
http://linux-user.ru/distributivy-linux/programmy-dlya-linux/lokalnyj-server-lamp-dlya-ubuntu-linux-mint/
http://ubuntovod.ru/instructions/web-server-ubuntu-php-mysql.html
Апач показывает свою дефолтную страницу. Поменять, как сказано в статьях выше не получается.(т.е. я меняю, но результата - ноль) 
на команду `sudo service apache2 restart`
Апач ругается и отключается.

Командой `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` слетает mysql, поэтому ставил все вручную.
Наверно я накосячил с апачем, но не знаю где.
В `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf` вписал

```
ServerName tset.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
DocumentRoot /home/anton/php/test.com/public
```

далее

```
sudo a2ensite test.com
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

пишет:

```
[....] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.serviceapache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
failed!
```

делаю `sudo gedit /etc/hosts`
итоговый вид hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test.com
127.0.1.1   anton-N751JK
127.0.0.1   test.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

`default-ssl.conf` не менял

в `/home/anton/php/test.com/public` создал `index.html` с текстом. захожу на `test.com` и получаю: **Не удается получить доступ к сайту**

Что я сделал не так или не сделал? Скажите пожалуйста!

Все попавшиеся мне руководства были написаны в 2011-2014 годах. Как я понимаю, версии пакетов поменялись, многие команды стали ненужны. 
Подскажите годное руководство! или как начать осваивать php - минимально чтобы что-то хоть заработало.

**P.S.:** до этого кодил на ruby, у него все работает из коробки.
И да, я совсем ничего не понимаю в админстве и работе с серверами, есть такие люди, будьте толерантны.

Comment: Так а зачем Вам на убунте lamp? Apache уже будет по умолчанию. Установите php и мускул через `apt-get install php` и `apt-get install mysql-server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще то в php с версии 5.4 есть локальный сервер и запускаеться он вот т

```
php -S localhost:8080 file.php
```

где

1. -S - запустить сервер
2. localhost - ip адресс либо домен
3. 8080 - порт сервера
4. file.php - файл для обработки запросов, по умолчанию пустой

Есть минусы:

1. Обрабатывает все запросы одним файлом ( так как разработан под zend framework) для меня не проблема все мои проэкты используют один фаил для обработки запросов.
2. Сервер только для разработки

Все перечисленые минусы являютьься своего рода плюсами так как:

1. Лёгкий не  забивает память и проц (легче nginx) сравнивать с монстром по имени apache вообще не буду, да и среда разработки на нём просто насилие  над компом, драгоценые ресурсы машины лучше пустить на idea,php,mysql чем на вебсервер apache.
2. Сделан специально для разработки логи тут же выводяться в консоль, отображение ошибок одна строка в коде.
3. Не обрабатывает статику.

Comment: большое Вам спасибо! Именно это мне и нужно было!

Comment: @ToshiDono Обращайтесь! Удачи в изучение php.

Answer (score -1):

Вот отличный мануал http://senokosov.info/lamp/install-lamp

А почему бы Вам не попробовать использовать docker или vagrant - и ничего настраивать не надо.

Comment: lamp первый вышел по запросу ubuntu локальный сервер

Comment: не получается перезагрузить апач командой `sudo service apache2 reload` . пишет `apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.`

Comment: поправил в 00-default.conf на оригинальные настройки. теперь перезагрузки не требует, но тестовый сайт не запускает.

Comment: как использовать vargant или docker? разве это не усложняет задачу? дополнительные виртуальные машины.. я потерялся. разработка на php всегда такая запутанная?

Comment: @ToshiDono, вы сами себя путаете, пытаясь в линуксе действовать как в Windows. В линуксе изначально есть всё что нужно, и никаких костылей в виде *amp тут не требуется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.